# Accessing an Object from Within an Object

Tags: matlab

I have created a `TestData` object that is use by multiple files to put data in a particular format. Here is the class (snipped down version):

```
classdef TestData
properties
    metaData  = [];  % stores meta data in Nx2 array
end

methods
%% Getters    
    %Meta-Data
    function metaData = get.metaData(this)
       metaData = this.metaData; 
    end    

%% Setters
    %Meta-data
    function this = set.metaData(this, metaData)
        this.metaData = metaData;
    end
end %methods
end %class
```

One of the files that has access to it is my `FileIO` object. This handles the case of there being an external file instead of raw data. The problem I seem to be having is with the interface between the two objects. My intent is to be able to read in a file using the `readDataFromFile` function in `FileIO`; organize the data inside the `FileIO` object; and then pass that data to the `TestData` object, where it can be combed through for final verification and then written to a separate external file.

```
classdef FileIO < TestData

methods

    function this = readDataFromFile(this, thisFile)
        [filepath, name, ext] = fileparts(thisFile);  
        inFile = textread(thisFile, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');

        this = this.setMetaDataFromFile(inFile, ext);
        myTestData = TestData;
        myTestData.metaData = this;    
    end %readDataFromFile        

    function this = setMetaDataFromFile(this, inFile, ext)
        strForm = string(inFile);

        if strcmp(ext, '.txt')
            dataBegin = find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(inFile, 'start of data')));
            metaDataBegin = find(~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(inFile, 'meta data')));
            metaDataOutForm = strForm(metaDataBegin+1:dataBegin-4);
            metaDataOutForm = cellfun(@(x)strsplit (x, '='), metaDataOutForm, 'UniformOutput', false);

            this.metaData = cat(1,metaDataOutForm{:});
        end
    end

end % Methods
end % Class
```

I tried inheritance and I have been racking my brain with this for a bit and I just can't seem to be able to find the solution. I can do this no problem from other files that are not `classes`, which is why I am under the assumption it has to do with the two objects trying to interact. The line where I make an instance of `TestData` and the the line directly below it are just one of my many attempts to try and solve this issue.

Thank you for the help in advance. If there is anything else I can offer please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for inheritance here.

The closest solution to your current code would be something like this:

```
classdef FileIO
properties
    metaData  = [];  % stores meta data in Nx2 array
end
methods

    function myTestData = readDataFromFile(this, thisFile)
        [filepath, name, ext] = fileparts(thisFile);
        inFile = textread(thisFile, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
        this = this.setMetaDataFromFile(inFile, ext);
        myTestData = TestData;
        myTestData.metaData = this.metaData;
    end %readDataFromFile        

    function this = setMetaDataFromFile(this, inFile, ext)
        % ...
    end

end % Methods
end % Class
```

Here, `FileIO.readDataFromFile` returns a `TestData` object. You'd write:

```
myFileIO = FileIO;
myTestData = myFileIO.readDataFromFile('filename');
```

But I think that is a really ugly use of a class, if you create an object, call a single function in it, and then never use the object again, it means you need to have a free function:

```
    function myTestData = readDataFromFile(this, thisFile)

    [filepath, name, ext] = fileparts(thisFile);
    inFile = textread(thisFile, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
    metaData = getMetaDataFromFile(inFile, ext);
    myTestData = TestData;
    myTestData.metaData = metaData;

    function metaData = getMetaDataFromFile(inFile, ext)
    % ...
```

Here, `getMetaDataFromFile` is a private function (assuming you don't need to call this on its own). Now you just do:

```
myTestData = readDataFromFile('filename');
```

Note that the free function version is easier to call (don't need to create an object that you don't really use), and its code is shorter because it doesn't have a `classdef` around it.

---

Another alternative is to make `readDataFromFile` a method of the `TestData` class. Note that you can simply move the function we created above into a directory `@TestData` to make it a method, it doesn't need to be written inside the `classdef` file.

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression that I could only have one function per`.m` file. So is your suggestion implying that as long as the other functions in the file are private (i.e. they are only accessed by the function that the file is saved as) that there can be more than one function in a file? Also, there are four functions total: `metadata`, `data`, `colLabels`, `colUnits`; and so each of these would be called. Now, I did have these in the `TestData` object and they worked, but after I wrote the setters and getters they were not happy. It seemed cluttered so I moved them.

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: Indeed, you can define additional private functions within the same file. This helps a lot with structuring your code. If you need to write a private function shared among several functions, create an M-file in a subdirectory `private`.

Comment: I have been asked to design the object to have a constructor that takes in as arguments the meta data, labels, units, and data. This, however, poses a problem when I want to import a file because I will not know that values of anything until it is processed. What would your suggestion be? Would you implement different functions external to the object, or is there a way to read the file in with and set the arrays after calling some "generic" constructor that initializes the arrays to `[]`?

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: How about a constructor that takes either metadata+labels+units+data, or a file name? In the constructor you can test the number of type of input arguments, and do either one thing or the other. The constructor can also call itself, which maybe sounds weird, but you can do something like this in the constructor to `TestData`: `if nargin==1 && ischar(varargin{1}), out = TestData(load(varargin{1})), return, end`.

Comment: So, I have a function `readDataFromFile` that is a member function of `TestData`, can I just call that in the `if` statement? Also, `load` does not work because it is a `.txt` file I am importing, and from what I read every line must begin with a comment for it to work. So I used `this=TestData(textscan(varargin{1},'%s'`)). This compiles, but I still need to call the `readDataFromFile` function in order to sift through the file and sort the arrays. If you need a better understanding I'd be happy to make another post to show you more code. Thank you!

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: Yes, I guess you can do `this=readDataFromFile(this,...)`. Or you can make `readDataFromFile` a private function, not a class member, and call it just to load and process the data. I guess there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I was just a bit curious if there was a specific reason you recursively called the constructor.

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: Just for simplicity of code. I guess it's not necessary. It is just a possibility that I wanted to note, since you can't do that in other languages (that I know of).

Comment: Yes, it's very interesting. Thanks for noting it. I will be using this language a lot over the coming years and any information helps.